# Cannot start server in new window because no terminal app was specified

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

In react naitve when I install or add external Library in my project then they easy installed but when I intigrate the project or use this Library in whole project then i use " react-native run-android" this command they show me this error.

I try every command like,
npx react-native run-android
npm start
npx react-native start,

And also change the port
npm start -- --port=8088

BUT I CAN'T FIND THE SOLUTION

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use npx react-native run-android --terminal powershell